# Django session data is lost when using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I have two simple views:

```py
def form_view(request):
    form = MyModelForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid()
                form.save()
                uuid = uuid4()
                request.session["uuid"] = uuid.hex
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("thanks"))
    return render(request, "form.jinja2", {"form": form})

# the url obtained by reverse("thanks") maps to this view
def redirect_view(request):
    if "uuid" in request.session: # this returns false in prodcution
        return render(request, "thanks.jinja2", {"uuid": request.session["uuid"]}
    return redirect("/")
```

The code works in development, i.e I can fetch data from request.session, but in production it does not work, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I have tried to set `request.session.modified = True`, set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False` in settings and also tried using `request.session.set_test_cookie()` and `request.session.test_cookie_worked()` in the two different views, i.e setting the cookie in `form_view` and testing the cookie in `redirect_view`, but it returned false. Interestingly, if I do this:

```py
def form_view(request):
    form = MyModelForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.session.test_cookie_worked()) # this prints True!
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid()
                form.save()
                uuid = uuid4()
                request.session["uuid"] = uuid.hex
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("thanks"))
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    return render(request, "form.jinja2", {"form": form})
```

The `test_cookie_worked()` returns `True`.

I have tried many of the solutions recommended when searching on something similar, but none of these work for me, and I don't know what else to try.

Relevant settings for both environments are:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

Both the production environment and development are running over https.

Edit: Doing some more investigation, it seems django is not receiving cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with varnish. Varnish deleted the cookies, so I added an exception for this site and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).